# Why is ng-bind-html not rendering out html? It's rendering out a string

Tags: angularjs

I've not been able to render out html to a view that's being retrieved via an api call. Below is the code I'm using, is there anything else I can try?

I'm using Angular 1.5

[here is a plunker link to my code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cd0aXPVoufvdxfFmJfjp?p=info)

```
var htmlData = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;PART TIME MAINTENANCE&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;We are currently seeking a person to assist with general maintenance &lt;/a&gt;).&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'
$scope.content = function() {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlData);
};


p(ng-bind-html="content()")
```

Comment: That `p (ng-bind-html...)` doesn't look right. What does your actual template look like?

Comment: Don't you have any errors? Do you pass $sce service to your controller? Does your html `p(ng-bind-html="content()"` covered with this controller? Please provide working [plunker](https://plnkr.co) example, so we could see more details

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Cd0aXPVoufvdxfFmJfjp?p=info

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I'm using jade to build my html templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't angular, the problem was with html entities being returned from the api. Everything started working as expected once that was solved.